# Vim pasting causes copy into clipboard?

Tags: vim, clipboard, vimrc

So this is strange. If I have the following:

```
function noTypo(){return;}
fucntion doSomething(){return;}
fucntion doSomethingElse(){return;}
```

And I highlight and yank `function` in `function noTypo()`, and I invoke visual mode and paste over `fucntion` with `p`, it pastes `function`. Good. But Vim then copies the value that was just pasted (`fucntion`) into my clipboard, such that when I paste a *second* time, the value that gets pasted is `fucntion`. How do I *keep* the original `function` value in the clipboard? Am I crazy?

Comment: What is "paste" here?

Comment: Ah good point. By copy I mean `yank` and paste I mean `p`

Comment: Have you tried `"0p` to paste the last thing that was explicitly yanked?